# html only vertically stacked bar chart

Tags: html, css, charts, outlook

I am trying to create a vertically stacked bar chart to use in emails; the client is primarily Outlook 2016.

I don't want to use images because, in my scenario, the user will always be asked to download images and may not bother. Outlook doesn't support jQuery, JavaScript, or `div`s with positions.

Here is the really simple code I have to produce two identical bars (yes, I know it is horrible):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:10px">
          <table style="border: none;border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
              <td style="height:10px">
                <table style="border: none;
                    border-collapse: collapse;width:40px;
                    mso-table-lspace:0pt;
                    mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="height:50px;background-color:red;">
                      <p>1</p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="border: none;
                    border-collapse: collapse;width:40px;
                    mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                  <tr>
                    <td style="height:10px;background-color:green;">
                      <p>1</p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td style="height:10px">
                <p>
                  <table style="border: none;
                      border-collapse: collapse;width:40px;
                      mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="height:50px;background-color:red;">
                        <p>1</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <table style="border: none;
                      border-collapse: collapse; width:40px;
                      mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
                    <tr>
                      <td style="height:10px;background-color:green;">
                        <p>1</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

This works fine and I have extended into charts that look like this rendered chart:

[image: rendered chart]

However, when a user forwards the email in Outlook, it adds `<p>` tags for me and makes the chart unreadable, like this:

[image: unreadable chart]

So I am looking for either a way to trick Outlook so it doesn't insert the `<p>` tags that force the chart to have white spaces in the bars, or a different way to create the chart in the first place using only HTML and CSS. No jQuery, no JavaScript, and no `div`s with float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlooks on Windows from 2007 to 2019 use Word's rendering engine, and they do add a lot of `<p>` and other stuff. There's no way to prevent this as far as I know. However, if you add them yourselves in the first place with the appropriate styles (`margin:0` to reset default paragraphs styles), you should be ok. But in your example, you shouldn't even need to add paragraphs in the first place. Here's a full working example simplified from your code (I tested this on a real Outlook 2019 and the code stays stable when replying or forwarding):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stacked bar chart</title>
    <!--[if mso]>
    <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding:2px; vertical-align:bottom;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; width:40px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height:50px; background-color:red;">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height:10px; background-color:green;">1</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td style="padding:2px; vertical-align:bottom;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border: none; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; width:40px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height:10px; background-color:red;">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height:50px; background-color:green;">1</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If this doesn't work for you, another approach could be to [use VML to render the entire graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/vml/web-workshop---specs---standards----how-to-use-vml-on-web-pages). But this will only work on Outlook-ish clients using Word's rendering engine or compatible with VML.

Comment: thank you, this has worked a treat! Is the main difference the  role="presentation" attribute?

Comment: No. The `role="presentation"` is there mostly for accessibility reasons (to prevent screen readers from reading out loud all the tables structure). The biggest difference in my code example is the removal of the `<p>` you had, and the use of more default styles and attributes.